FullCalendar 6 - How to hide scrollbar borders
I am using FullCalendar.js (version 6.1.15) in a web application developed with Visual Studio Code and tested on Chrome. My goal is to create a "customized black version" of FullCalendar in the dayGridMonth view.
Here is the configuration of my calendar:
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
      dateClick: function() {
        alert('a day has been clicked!');
      },
      firstDay: '1',
      fixedWeekCount: false,
      slotEventOverlap: false,
      themeSystem: 'bootstrap5',
      height: 'auto'
    });
    calendar.render();

Despite several attempts to hide the scrollbars and remove any borders using CSS, two gray lines remain visible: one on the side and another at the bottom of the calendar. I haven’t been able to hide or remove them.
Has anyone else encountered this issue? How can I get rid of these lines in my calendar rendering?
Many thanks !
I tried to set 'height' to 'auto' and here is my css code to hide scrollbars and borders:
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none !important; /* Completely hides scrollbars in Webkit browsers */
}


#calendar {
    background-color: none;
    font-size: 0.85rem;
}

.fc-col-header-cell-cushion, .fc-day-header {
    color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.fc-col-header-cell {
    border: none !important ;
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

.fc-col-header-cell:hover {
    background-color: #409AFF;
    cursor: pointer;
}

    .fc-col-header-cell:hover .fc-col-header-cell-cushion {
        background-color: #409AFF;
        color: white;
    }

.fc-daygrid-day {
    border: none !important;
}

.fc-daygrid-day:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.fc-daygrid-day:hover .fc-daygrid-day-number {
    color: #40d0ff;
    font-size: 900;
}

.fc-daygrid-day-number {
    color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.fc-toolbar {
    font-size: 12px;
    align-content:center;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #40d0ff;
}

.fc-toolbar .fc-toolbar-title {
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 3px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.fc-prev-button, .fc-next-button, .fc-today-button {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border: none !important;
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

.fc-prev-button:hover .fc-icon:before,
.fc-next-button:hover .fc-icon:before, 
.fc-today-button:hover {
    color: #40d0ff !important;
}

.fc-prev-button .fc-icon:before {
    content: "<";
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 900;
    padding-left:4px;
    padding-top:1px;
}

.fc-next-button .fc-icon:before {
    content: ">";
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 900;
    padding-left:4px;
    padding-top:1px;
}

.fc-scrollgrid {
    border: none !important;
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}

.fc-daygrid {
    border-collapse: collapse !important; /* Eliminate grid gaps */
    border: none !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
.fc-scrollgrid table  {
    background-color: none !important;
    border: none !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}



It looks like the <td role="presentation">, which is directly contained within <tr class="fc-scrollgrid-section">, still has the right and bottom borders.
Since the original rule for borders applies to both td and th, their borders can be disabled with:
.fc .fc-scrollgrid td,
.fc .fc-scrollgrid th {
  border: none;
}

